# How to intercept responses sent by TIdHTTPServer

Tags: c++builder, indy, vcl

I'm using C++Builder XE6 to write a simple HTTP server VCL application.

The application uses a `TListView` with `ViewStyle=vsReport` to display incoming requests and outgoing responses from a `TIdHTTPServer`. The `TListView` has columns for the properties of the request/response, such as the source IP, command (GET, POST, etc.), URI, protocol version (e.g. HTTP/1.1), headers, content, etc.

I know that incoming HTTP requests can be obtained through the `ARequestInfo` parameter of the `OnCommandGet` event handler. For example, to read the content of a POST request:

```
String S = ReadStringFromStream(ARequestInfo->PostStream);
```

The application responds to GET requests for certain URIs in the `OnCommandGet` event handler. For example:

```
if (SameText(ARequestInfo->URI, _D("/test")))
{
    AResponseInfo->ContentText = "My test response";
    AResponseInfo->ResponseNo = 200;
}
```

How do I intercept the outgoing responses that are sent by `TIdHTTPServer` (i.e. after the `OnCommandGet` event handler executes), so that I can display them in the `TListView`?

Comment: "*How do I intercept the outgoing responses that are sent by TIdHTTPServer*" - You can't. But what you can do instead is send the responses manually by calling `AResponseInfo->WriteHeader()` and `AResponseInfo->WriteContent()` from inside your `OnCommand...` event handler(s). Then `TIdHTTPServer` won't send its default responses after the `OnCommand...` events have exited.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Remy. I read that (most of) the `TIdIntercept...` classes don't implement server-side support, but sending the response in the `OnCommandGet` event handler is much simpler. I had no idea this was even possible. Thanks for your help, Remy.

Comment: For testing purposes, would it be possible to not respond to a request? Can I call `System::Sysutils::Abort()` in the `OnCommandGet` handler to prevent `TIdHTTPServer` from sending a response? Or is there another way to do this?

Comment: Intercepts are implemented at the `IOHandler` layer, not really client-side or server-side. You *can* create intercepts that are attached to `TIdHTTPServer` connections, but that is just going to give you raw data, not parsed data. In any case, `Abort()` will not work the way you want. `TIdHTTPServer` will just interpret that as an error and send a `500` response to the client. If you really want to prevent a response, you can set `AResponseInfo->HeaderHasBeenWritten=true` and leave both `AResponseInfo->ContentText` and `AResponseInfo->ContentStream` empty.